# Laravel where condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
$location = $details['location'];
    $specializationAreasName = $details['specialization_areas'];
    if($details['location'] == 'all'){
        $location = '';
    }
    if($specializationAreasName == 'all'){
        $specializationAreas = '1 = 1';
    }
    else{
        $specializationAreas = "'specialization_areas','like', '%'".$specializationAreasName."'%'";
    }

    $result = Lawyers :: with('SkillsMappedToLawyer')
                        ->where('location',$location)
                        ->where($specializationAreas)
                        ->take(10)->skip($skip)
                        ->get();
```

Please find my code If the location == all then I want to search for all or else I need to search for the criteria which is dynamic.
can some one help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$location = $details['location'];
$specializationAreasName = $details['specialization_areas'];

$query = Lawyers :: with('SkillsMappedToLawyer');

if($details['location'] != 'all'){
    $query = $query->where('location', $location);
}

if($specializationAreasName != 'all'){
    $query = $query->where('specialization_areas', 'LIKE', '%'.$specializationAreasName.'%');
}


$result = $query
             ->take(10)->skip($skip)
             ->get();
```